# I need a portable, consistent pseudorandom number generator

Tags: perl, prng

I am writing a [kid sister encryption](http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/the-kid-sister-crypto-manifesto/) function and I need a PRNG that produces consistent results across OSes (so no floating point math, taking advantage of hardware, or system level software).  It would be nice, but not necessary, for the PRNG had a period longer than 2<sup>30</sup>.

I am currently using a 32 bit [Xorshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{
    use integer; #use integer math
    my $x = 123456789;
    my $y = 362436069;
    my $w = 88675123; 
    my $z = 521288629;

    sub set_random_seed {
        $w = shift;
    }

    sub random { 
        my $t = $x ^ ($x << 11);
        $x = $y;
        $y = $z;
        $z = $w;
        my $rand = $w = ($w ^ ($w >> 19)) ^ ($t ^ ($t >> 8)); 
        return $rand % 256; #scale it back to a byte at a time
    }
}

set_random_seed(5);
print map { random(), "\n" } 1 .. 10;
```

But I am worried because I don't really understand how it works.  For example, the original source did not have an ability to set the seed, so I added one, but I don't know if I chose the correct variable for the seed.

So, all of that boils down to

1. Do you know of a module on CPAN that fits my needs?
2. If not, do you know of an algorithm that fits my needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Math::Random::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/search?module=Math%3A%3ARandom%3A%3AMT%3A%3AAuto) is a CPAN module implementing the well-known [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) PRNG.

Comment: But is it consistent?  If I seed it with 5 will it produce the same results on Linux, BSD, OS X, Win32, etc.

Comment: If you read that Wikipedia link, you'll notice the first thing it says under "Application" is that it's not suitable for cryptography.

Comment: @cjm: if you read that kid sister encryption link, you'll notice that's probably not relevant.

Comment: Yeah, the algorithm I am using really isn't any stronger than ROT13. It is there to give people who don't know any better a warm fuzzy feeling.  I am more worried about portability.

Answer (score 7):

Try using an LFSR - [Linear Feedback Shift Register.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).  T[he first link](http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr.htm) on the external links has everything you need to produce any number of bits of randomness.  The nice thing about this is that it is easy to implement and can be done using all integer math.

I've used it with success on an 8051 project.  With perl it will be a snap.

**Update:**

Here's a quick perl implementation of an 8 bit LFSR:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(reduce);
use vars qw($a $b);

print 'Taps: ', set_taps( 8, 7, 2, 1 ), "\n";
print 'Seed: ', seed_lfsr( 1 ), "\n";
print read_lfsr(), "\n" for 1..10;

BEGIN {
    my $tap_mask;
    my $lfsr = 0;

    sub read_lfsr {
        $lfsr = ($lfsr >> 1) ^ (-($lfsr & 1) & $tap_mask );

        return $lfsr;
    }

    sub seed_lfsr {
        $lfsr = shift || 0;
        $lfsr &= 0xFF;
    }

    sub set_taps {
        my @taps = @_;

        $tap_mask = reduce { $a + 2**$b } 0, @taps;

        $tap_mask >>= 1;

        $tap_mask &= 0xFF;

        return $tap_mask;
    }
}
```

This code is just a prototype.  If I wanted to use it in production I'd probably wrap it in a object and make register size configurable.  Then we'd be rid of those pesky shared variables.

Comment: Clicking through to the wiki shows a whole family of fascinating functions.  This is just neat.