# Generate 1000 random 10 digit number using javascript in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, random

I want to generate atleast 1000 unique random numbers with 10 digit using 
javascript in a loop. Is this possible? Or is Javascript a wrong thing to do this?

**UPDATE:** How will you be sure that duplicates are not created?

Comment: Yes, this is possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you want hints on doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
var arr = [],
    track = [],
    min = 1000000000,
    max = 9999999999,
    qty = 1000,
    ii = 0,
    rnd;

while (ii < qty) {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    if (!track[rnd]) {
        arr[ii] = track[rnd] = rnd;
        ii += 1;
    }
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mTmEs/

Now, if something went awry with `Math.random` and for some reason it were to generate a lot of duplicates, this code could take a long time to complete. I don't think there is any way around this kind of potential problem though when you're talking about large quantities of unique random numbers.

Comment: I would change track to an Object, now track is an array with an AWFUL lot of elements. Using an object will be faster.

Comment: Your method in my test takes 8-9 msec, using one array with a loop to check for duplicates takes 40-50 msec, and using an object and recovering an array of 10 digit numbers from it takes 90+ msec.

Comment: @Creynders: The way Fish is using the array, it's exactly the same as using a non-array object; no speed difference. He/she isn't using the array-ish-ness of it at all, and of course, JavaScript arrays [are just objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), not really arrays.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're quite right, just did a small test and there's no substantial speed difference. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

1. Use `Math.random` to generate the pseudo-random numbers. `Math.random` returns a pseudo-random number greater than or equal to `0` and less than `1`, so to get a 10-digit number (I'm assuming a whole number), you'd multiple that by 1,000,000,000 and round it off with `Math.round` or `Math.floor`. (If you need them *all* to be 10 digits, adjust accordingly — adding a base amount, multiplying by a higher number, etc.)
2. Use an object to keep track of them, so `var obj = {};` to start with.
3. Store the numbers as keys in an object, e.g. `obj[number] = true`.
4. Test whether the object has the generated number using `if (obj[number])`
5. Loop until you have the correct number of unique numbers.

The reason I use an object for storing the numbers is that JavaScript objects are maps by their nature, and engines are optimized to retrieve properties from objects quickly. Under the covers, an implementation can do what it likes, but will probably use a hash table or similar.

Note that using an "array" for this is unnecessary; [JavaScript arrays aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects with a couple of special features.

Comment: multiplying with 1,000,000,000 does not guarantee 10 digit number

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman: I assumed he meant 10 digits *or less*. (Your downvote, or someone else's? Seems rather strong for such a small flaw.)

Comment: I'd agree that 10-digit numbers included the smaller numbers that would be padded with 0s on the left.   I guess it comes down to whether you consider 01 a two-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in JS, but you would have to check the array to see if it contains the currently generated random number.  This would obviously degrade performance.

See if these answers help.

[Random number generator that fills an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280725/random-number-generator-that-fills-an-interval)

[Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Answer (score 1):

A generic function for generating n random numbers of length l might be:

```
// Generate n unique random numbers of length l
// l should be less than 15
function genNRandLen(n, l) {

  // Make sure l and n are numbers
  n = Number(n);
  l = Number(l);

  // Protect against bad input
  if (isNaN(l) || isNaN(n)) return;

  var o = {}, a = [], num;
  var min = l == 1? 0 : Math.pow(10, l-1);
  var r = Math.pow(10, l) - min;

  // Protect against endless loop
  if (n >= (r)) return;

  while (n--) {
    do {
      num = Math.floor(min + (Math.random()*r));
    } while (o[num])

    o[num] = true;
    a[n] = num;
  }
  return a.sort();
}
```

Sorting is just to make it easy to see duplicates when testing, remove if not necessary or random order is preferred.

If numbers longer than 15 digits are required, they can be created by concatenating strings of shorter random numbers and trimming to the required length. The following will generate a random number of any length:

```
// Generate random number of length l
function randLen(l) {
  var n = '';
  while (n.length < l) {
    n += String(Math.random()).replace(/^0\.0*/,'');
  }
  return n.substring(0, l);
}
```

It must return a string since converting to number will mess with the results. Oh, and all numbers are integers.

Answer (score -2):

Why not? Here is the code:

```
var a=[]; 
for (var i=1000; i--;) 
 a.push(Math.random()*10000000000)
```

Comment: I believe this has the potential to create duplicates.

Comment: That doesn't guarantee the number has 10 digits.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you both. But may be it ok for this particular task. And other checks will be just an unnecessary complication.

Comment: No. The question specifically says **unique** random numbers.